# Database Recovery Model alter script error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to deploy one of our server via teamcity (db project in VS 2012), i am getting an error on Staging server

> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>   Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
>
> Error SQL72045: Script execution error.

The executed script:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
BEGIN
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
END
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that i am trying to publish this via High Availability DB, basically it mirror to other DB's

Comment: Is your script running in SQLCMD mode? Otherwise, `$(DatabaseName)` is invalid syntax.

Comment: What's your DB context when you run this command?  Try `USE [master];` immediately before.

Comment: The scripts are executing without any problem with other servers, but on the Stage server we have Database High Availability server where this will mirror the 2 other database, The problem i see here   visual studio generated DB script on deployment is  trying to alter  the server property, which is **SET RECOVERY SIMPLE**, if I exclude from the script, the problem goes away, but i am note sure where i can disable this option not to generate.

Comment: Guys, I have fixed adding `<ScriptDatabaseOptions>False</ScriptDatabaseOptions>` in the publish.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Don't just gloss over the problem: understand it.

It's because you have some sort of HA (you said mirroring in the comment above, but availability groups (for sure) or log shipping (I think) would also cause this) that requires that the database be in full recovery. When you try to set it to simple recovery, it fails because you can't set the recovery model to anything but full for such a database. You could guard against this by checking what environment you're deploying to from VS and act accordingly.